# Angular Material1 multiple view rendering in the content section of left side nav

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am going to create a webpage with angular material 1. In the webpage, I will show a toolbar and left nav(kind of a master page). In the content section(md-content) of the page(right side of the left menu), I will show multiple views mostly independent of each other.
Please suggest me a way to do it. Whether to use ng-switch, ng-include or separate nested controller(where parent is AppCtrl) or independent controllers. Please note that I will use ng-route to update the url based on the content shown/menu item clicked.

Example taken from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" style="height:500px;" ng-cloak="" class="sidenavdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
```

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')" md-whiteframe="4">

  <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
    <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content layout-padding="" ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
    <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-md="">
      Close Sidenav Left
    </md-button>
    <p hide="" show-gt-md="">
      This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
      narrow your display.
    </p>
  </md-content>

</md-sidenav>

<md-content flex="" layout-padding="">



</md-content>

<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">

  <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
    <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content ng-controller="RightCtrl" layout-padding="">
    <form>
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="testInput">Test input</label>
        <input type="text" id="testInput" ng-model="data" md-autofocus="">
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
    <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
      Close Sidenav Right
    </md-button>
  </md-content>

</md-sidenav>
```